# Igraph - Remove weakest edge from every triangle

Tags: r, igraph

Say I have a large network and I want to remove, for every triangle, the weakest edge based on its weight. So if the graph

**A - B, B - C, C - A, D - A** has weights 
**0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1**

respectively, remove **C - A** (the vertex D isn't part of a triangle).

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a slightly more interesting example that has two triangles:

```
dat <- data.frame(V1=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "D"), V2=c("B", "C", "A", "A", "B"), wt=c(0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

For later convenience, we will order the vertices alphabetically

```
dat <- data.frame(V1=pmin(dat$V1, dat$V2), V2=pmax(dat$V1, dat$V2), wt=dat$wt)
```

Let's look at our graph:

```
library(igraph)
G <-graph.data.frame(dat, directed=FALSE)
plot(G, edge.label=E(G)$wt)
```

[image]

The igraph `cliques` function can find all the triangles (which are cliques of size 3):

```
(triangles <- do.call(rbind, lapply(cliques(G, min=3, max=3), function(x) sort(V(G)$name[x]))))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "A"  "B"  "C" 
# [2,] "A"  "B"  "D"
```

To identify the minimum-weight edges to remove such that we get rid of all the triangles, I propose an integer programming formulation, where we have a binary variable for each edge indicating whether it is removed. We have a constraint for each triangle that requires that at least one edge in the triangle is removed. The objective is to minimize the sum of the weights of the removed edges. This is pretty straightforward to do with the `lpSolve` package, and I do it in the function below, which puts all our steps together:

```
library(lpSolve)
min.cost.removal <- function(dat) {
  dat <- data.frame(V1=pmin(dat$V1, dat$V2), V2=pmax(dat$V1, dat$V2), wt=dat$wt)
  G <-graph.data.frame(dat, directed=FALSE)
  triangles <- do.call(rbind, lapply(cliques(G, min=3, max=3), function(x) sort(V(G)$name[x])))
  constr <- t(apply(triangles, 1, function(x) (dat$V1 == x[1] & dat$V2 == x[2]) +
                                              (dat$V1 == x[1] & dat$V2 == x[3]) +
                                              (dat$V1 == x[2] & dat$V2 == x[3])))
  mod <- lp(objective.in = dat$wt,
            const.mat = constr,
            const.dir = rep(">=", nrow(triangles)),
            const.rhs = rep(1, nrow(triangles)),
            all.bin = TRUE)
  dat[mod$solution >= 0.999,]
}
```

For our graph, integer programming correctly identifies that the minimum-cost approach to removing all the triangles is removing edges A-C and A-D:

```
min.cost.removal(dat)
#   V1 V2  wt
# 3  A  C 0.2
# 4  A  D 0.1
```

If we significantly decrease the weight on edge A-B (I decrease it to 0.2 here), then removing that edge becomes the cheapest way to remove both triangles at the same time:

```
dat <- data.frame(V1=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "D"), V2=c("B", "C", "A", "A", "B"), wt=c(0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
min.cost.removal(dat)
#   V1 V2  wt
# 1  A  B 0.2
```